# Android spilts, different resources per abi

Tags: android, android-ndk, assets

I'm trying to set up splits which should include different asset files for different abis.

However, when trying to run it on my x86 emulator, I get the following errors during build:

```
Cannot build selected target ABI: x86, no suitable splits configured: arm64-v8a;
Cannot build selected target ABI: x86, no suitable splits configured: armeabi-v7a;
Cannot build selected target ABI: x86, no suitable splits configured: x86_64;
```

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.mnemosyne"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments '-DANDROID_STL=c++_static'
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "abi"

    productFlavors {
        armeabi_v7a {
            dimension "abi"
            ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
        }

        arm64_v8a {
            dimension "abi"
            ndk.abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
        }

        x86 {
            dimension "abi"
            ndk.abiFilters 'x86'
        }

        x86_64 {
            dimension "abi"
            ndk.abiFilters 'x86_64'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        armeabi_v7a  {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['../dependencies/python/lib/armeabi-v7a']
            assets.srcDirs = ['../dependencies/python/lib/armeabi-v7a/',
                              '../dependencies/python/lib/armeabi-v7a/modules/']
        }

        arm64_v8a {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['../dependencies/python/lib/arm64-v8a']
            assets.srcDirs = ['../dependencies/python/lib/arm64-v8a/',
                              '../dependencies/python/lib/arm64-v8a/modules/']
        }

        x86 {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['../dependencies/python/lib/x86']
            assets.srcDirs = ['../dependencies/python/lib/x86/',
                              '../dependencies/python/lib/x86/modules/']
        }

        x86_64 {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['../dependencies/python/lib/x86_64']
            assets.srcDirs = ['../dependencies/python/lib/x86_64',
                              '../dependencies/python/lib/x86_64/modules/']
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            version '3.10.2'
            path 'src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    }
}
```